# smallest subsets with sum larger than value in python

Tags: python, sum, sublist

What is the fastest way, given a list of lists of different dimensions,
to find all the smallest subsets with sum larger or equal to a specific value?

So that if the set and the value are

```
A = [[1],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[10],[1000,12],[11]]
value = 10
```

The solution would be

```
res = [[10],[11]]
```

or again:

```
A = [[1,10],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[10,10],[1000,12,1],[1,10,11]]
value = 10
res = [[1,10],[10,10]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share a way that you found and isn't fast enough? Or what exactly means fast?

Comment: I didn't find a way at the moment

Comment: Most likely yo are aware that you should present your own attempts ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). I'm sure you can definitely come up with something (even a partial solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following python code:
the code finds a list of lengths in A
then checks the sublists in ascending order, i.e.  sublists of size 1, then size 2, and then size 4. Note that the code does not check larger sublists if an smaller sublist is already included in the result.

```
A = [[1],[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[10],[1000,12],[11]]
value = 10

lens = list(set([len(i) for i in A]))   #result = [1,2,4]
res = []
for l in lens:
    if len(res) == 0: 
        for i in A: 
            if len(i) == l: 
                if sum(i) >= value: 
                    res.append(i)
print(res)   #result = [[10], [11]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was talking about in my (2<sup>nd</sup>) comment. Use a simple list comprehension to find out **all** the sublists that satisfy the condition:

> ```py
> >>> lists = [[1], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [10], [1000, 12], [11]]
> >>> value = 10
> >>>
> >>> [l for l in lists if sum(l) >= value]
> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [10], [1000, 12], [11]]
> ```

So, we have something that works but might be considered slow (well, not this particular example, but for larger input lists). It **is** slow because it searches for all the sublists that satisfy the condition, when in fact only the ones of **length 1** (in this case) should be attempted.

The 1<sup>st</sup> thing that comes into my mind is sorting the sublists in the input list based on their length. But sorting itself could be slow too, and actually we only need to group them. One way is using a dictionary, where keys are sublists lengths, and for a specific key, the value is a list containing all the sublists having that length:

> ```py
> >>> d = {}
> >>> for l in lists:
> ...     d.setdefault(len(l), []).append(l)
> ...
> >>> d
> {1: [[1], [10], [11]], 4: [[1, 2, 3, 4]], 2: [[5, 6], [1000, 12]]}
> >>>
> >>> ret = []
> >>>
> >>> for i in sorted(d):  # Traverse the (sorted) lengths
> ...     for l in d[i]:
> ...         if sum(l) >= value:
> ...             ret.append(l)
> ...     if ret:  # Once a specific length was handled, if there are some results, simply stop
> ...         break
> ...
> >>>
> >>> ret
> [[10], [11]]
> ```

Or, as a function:

```py
def filter_sublists(sublists, min_sum_threshold):
    d = {}
    for l in sublists:
        d.setdefault(len(l), []).append(l)
    ret = []
    for i in sorted(d):
        for l in d[i]:
            if sum(l) >= min_sum_threshold:
                ret.append(l)
        if ret:
            break
    return ret
```